# Does this look right for adding a terms of use checkbox to register form?

Tags: 6, users

And also, how can I get node/terms to open target="_blank"?

```
<?php


function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'user_register') {
  $form['legal'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('legal'),    
    );
  $form['legal']['select'] = array(
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#title' => t('Terms of Use<span class="form-required" title="' . t('This field is required') . '">*</span>'),
      '#default_value' => 0,
      '#description' => t('I certify that I am over the age of 18, and I have read and agree to the '.l('Terms of use.','node/terms').''),     
    );   
  $form['#validate'][] ='customfunctions_form_validate_custom';
  }  

}  



function MYMODULE_form_validate_custom($form, &$form_state) {
    $legal = $form_state['values']['select'];  
    if ($legal == 0) {
        form_set_error('select', 'Please check the agreement.');
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: You know there is a module for just this. http://drupal.org/project/legal

Comment: Why use a module when a few lines of code will do?

Comment: +1 @ Jeremy French,  however I think he just needs a checkbox to the form, whereas, legal module will a separate term of use page.

Comment: Legal handles things like changing T&Cs. Nothing to stop you rolling your own if you want to.

Comment: iStryker is right.  I am just making sure my code is correct.  I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: I'm confuse where this node/terms links is going

Comment: It's going to http://example.com/node/terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but I would change

```
$form['#validate'][] ='customfunctions_form_validate_custom';
```

to

```
$form['#validate'][] ='MYMODULE_user_registration_form_validate';
```

and

```
function MYMODULE_form_validate_custom($form, &$form_state) {
```

to

```
function MYMODULE_user_registration_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
```

Nothing wrong with your code, but this just keep with the Drupal naming convention ie search_form_validate,  node_form_validate, etc

Also

```
'#title' => t('Terms of Use<span class="form-required" title="' . t('This field is required') . '">*</span>'),
```

is bad

```
'#title' => t('Terms of Use') . "<span class='form-required' title='" . t('This field is required') . "'>*</span>",
```